# Virtual Machine with Vagrant is not accesible from the client the first time

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtualbox, packer

I'm trying to run a Rails project using Nginx with docker and vagrant. Everything is ok if I use the vagrant box ubuntu/trusty64, I provision the VM and everything is ok. But I wanted to create my own box from ubuntu/trusty64 and this is when all my problems began.

So I created the box using packer and this template:

```
{
      "variables": {
        "home": "{{env `HOME`}}"
      },
      "provisioners": [
        {
          "type": "shell",
          "execute_command": "echo 'vagrant'|sudo -S sh '{{.Path}}'",
          "override": {
            "virtualbox-ovf": {
              "scripts": [
                "scripts/docker.sh",
                "scripts/ansible.sh",
                "scripts/cleanup.sh",
                "scripts/zerodisk.sh"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "post-processors": [
        {
          "type": "vagrant",
          "override": {
            "virtualbox": {
              "output": "ubuntu-14-04-x64-virtualbox.box"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "builders": [
        {
          "type": "virtualbox-ovf",
          "headless": "true",
          "boot_wait": "10s",
          "source_path": "{{user `home`}}/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64/14.04/virtualbox/box.ovf",
          "ssh_username": "vagrant",
          "ssh_password": "vagrant",
          "ssh_port": 22,
          "ssh_wait_timeout": "10000s",
          "shutdown_command": "echo 'shutdown -P now' > /tmp/shutdown.sh; echo 'vagrant'|sudo -S sh '/tmp/shutdown.sh'",
          "vboxmanage": [
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--memory", "512" ],
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--cpus", "1" ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Then added the box to pedrof/base-box in vagrant boxes and used this Vagrantfile to start the VM:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |v|
    v.memory = 2048
    v.cpus = 2
  end

  config.vm.box = 'pedrof/base-box'
  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', type: 'nfs', mount_options: ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime,actimeo=1']
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: '172.17.8.100'
  config.vm.provision 'shell', path: "docker/build.sh"
  config.vm.provision 'shell', path: "docker/init.sh", run: 'always'
end
```

It starts the VM and starts docker containers using docker-compose. Everything is ok, except that I can't access http://172.17.8.100 from the browser but ping respond ok from the host. I ran curl to hit Nginx from inside the VM and it responded with the proper index page, but nothing from outside the VM. The weird thing is that everything works fine if I reload vagrant using `vagrant reload`.

Am I building the box incorrectly? Something is missing in the Vagrantfile?

Comment: When you curl from within the VM are you using the new interface/IP or localhost?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you start a docker container inside the Vagrant box. The container is a web server and you want to access the web server with your browser. Then you will need port forwarding to your host machine.

So first your container port must be mapped onto a box port. This is done by the -p Docker Parameter. Example: -p 8080:8080. Then the port will be available inside the box. You say, that you can access inside the box so I think this already correctly configured.

Try to forward this port out of the box. Add this to your Vagrantfile

```
...
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
...
```

> Now try to access port 8080 with http://localhost:8080

If you want to make http://172.17.8.100 work then you will have to map the container port onto port 80 of the box port which needs root access.